# How to create lambda boto3 function to create cloudformation stack in another Aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a lambda function which can create cloudformation stack in another Aws account and taking template from S3 bucket in
source account.

Comment: Any problems, errors in particular? What is your current code and why it does not work?

Comment: Try and break it down. You will need to generate a CFN template and save it in the source account S3, then you'll need to set up an cross-account to copy the file between the two accounts, then on the destination account you will trigger the Lambda to create the CFN template. What you want to do is put the CFN in the S3 bucket and call a Lambda via URL to execute on the destination account and copy the S3 file across and execute the CFN template.

Comment: @JeremyThompson i have cfn template ready but i dont know how to write a complete code in lambda using boto3. Can you help me in providing full lambda code?

Answer (score 1):

AWS CloudFormation can only be run from the AWS Account where resources will be deployed.

Therefore, the AWS Lambda function in Account-A would need to:

- Call `AssumeRole()` on an IAM Role in Account-B, which will provide temporary credentials for Account-B
- Use those temporary credentials to call `CreateStack()` to create the CloudFormation stack in Account-B

The template file used to create the stack can be passed as part of the `CreateStack()` call, or it can be referenced via an AmazonS3 URL. If the template is coming from Account-A, then the S3 bucket would need to make that object accessible to Account-B (eg via Bucket Policy or ACL).

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

Comment: i have created assume role as you mentioned above but i am getting confused in writing proper lambda function for above requirement. @https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson

Comment: Example code for AssumeRole: [Switching to an IAM role (AWS API) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html)

Comment: what code shall i write for cloudformation in boto3?

Comment: From Python, use [`create_stack()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack) to launch a CloudFormation stack.